# How do you detect when an image has been deleted from WordPress media library?

Tags: images, media-library

I want to detect when the user click "Delete permanently" in media library so that I can use the post ID of said image to remove the image from my plugin. I have the below code, but it's not working.

```
var avatarFrame = wp.media({
    title   : title,
    library : { type : 'image' },
    multiple: false
});
avatarFrame.on( 'close', function() { 
   var id = avatarFrame.state().get( 'selection' ).first().toJSON().id
});
avatarFrame.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `before_delete_post` action hook for this purpose as it triggers just before WordPress deletes a post (or media) which allows you to utilize its ID in time.

```
function my_plugin_image_deleted( $post_id ) {
    // Ensure type is attachment (could be a page, post, etc. otherwise)
    if ( 'attachment' === get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
        // Your code here - you have the $post_id to play with!
        // ...
    }
}
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'my_plugin_image_deleted' );
```

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem. The deletion of the image is done by WordPress using JavaScript. I want to know if I can use wp.media (JavaScript) to detect when the image has been deleted. I am currently using wp.media to detect when the image has been selected, but I don't know how to detect when it has been deleted. When the user click "Delete permanently" WordPress provides a confirm popup for the user to confirm, so I am not able to add an event listener to the "Delete permanently" button.

Comment: @www.matemingler.com You don't need javascript to delete the images in your plugin. You can do this on the PHP side using the code I suggested. Why would you do it on the JavaScript side? Isn't the data of what images are stored in your plugin are stored in a database or some kind? Say you want to do it in JS, then what? Your other JS script won't need to call some Ajax to do the deletion?

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks for your help.